# Getting error "The campingList JavaScript controller doesn't appear to be checking if form fields are valid."

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, aura

while doing Aura input data using forms trail (https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics/lex_dev_lc_basics_forms) challenge, I am getting following error:

The campingList JavaScript controller doesn't appear to be checking if form fields are valid.

My code is as follows:

**campingList.cmp**

```
<aura:component >

<aura:attribute name="items" type="Camping_Item__c[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="newItem" type="Camping_Item__c"
                default="{'sobjectType' : 'Camping_Item__c',
                           'Name': '',
                           'Packed__c': false,
                           'Quantity__c' : 0,
                           'Price__c' : 0}"/>
<ol>

    <li>Bug Spray</li>

    <li>Bear Repellant</li>

    <li>Goat Food</li>

</ol>

<fieldset class="slds-box slds-theme--default slds-container--small">

<legend id="newCampItemForm" class="slds-text-heading--small 
  slds-p-vertical--medium">
  Add Camping Item
</legend>

<form class="slds-form--stacked">

  <lightning:input aura:id="itemname" 
                   label="Name"
                   name="itemname"
                   value="{!v.newItem.Name}"
                   required="true"
  />

  <lightning:input type="number" 
                   aura:id="quantity" 
                   label="Quantity"
                   name="quantityfield"
                   value="{!v.newItem.Quantity__c}"
                   min="1"
                   required="true"
   />

  <lightning:input type="number" 
                   aura:id="price" 
                   label="Price"
                   name="price"
                   value="{!v.newItem.Price__c}"
                   formatter="currency"
                   step="0.1"
  />

  <lightning:input type="checkbox" 
                   aura:id="itemform" 
                   label="Packed?"
                   name="packed"
                   checked="{!v.newItem.Packed__c}"
  />

  <lightning:button label="Create Camping Item"
                    variant="brand"
                    onclick="{!c.clickCreateItem}"
  />

</form>

 </fieldset>
 <div class ="slds-card slds-p-top--meduim">
  <header class ="slds-card__header">
     <h3 class = "slds-text-heading--small">Items</h3>
   </header>

   <section class ="slds-card__body">
      <div id="list" class = "row">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.items}" var="campItem">
                <c:campingListItem item="{!campItem}"/>
            </aura:iteration>
       </div>
    </section>

</div>

</aura:component>
```

**campingListItem.cmp**

```
<aura:component >
<aura:attribute name="item" type="Camping_Item__c" required="true"/>        

<p>Name: {!v.item.Name}</p>
<p>Price: <lightning:formattednumber value="{!v.item.Price__c}" 
                                     style="currency" 
                                     currencyCode="USD" />    </p>
<p>Quantity:<lightning:formattednumber value="{!v.item.Quantity__c}" />
</p>
<p>
   <lightning:input type="toggle"                           
                     label="Packed?"                          
                     name="packed"                        
                     checked="{!v.item.Packed__c}" 
   />
</p>

<div>
    <lightning:button label="Packed!" name='myButton' onclick="
     {!c.packItem}"/>
  </div>   

</aura:component>
```

**campingListController.js**

```
({
clickCreateItem: function(component, event, helper) {

    // Simplistic error checking
    var validItem = true;

    // Name must not be blank
    var nameField = component.find("itemname");
    var itemname = nameField.get("v.value");
    if ($A.util.isEmpty(itemname)){
        validItem = false;
        nameField.set("v.errors", [{message:"Item name can't be blank."}]);
    }
    else {
        nameField.set("v.errors", null);
    }

    // Quantity must not be blank
    var quantityField = component.find("quantity");
    var quantity = quantityField.get("v.value");
    if ($A.util.isEmpty(quantity) || isNaN(quantity) || (quantity <= 1)){
        validItem = false;
        quantityField.set("v.errors", [{message:"Quantity can't be blank."}]);
    }
    else {
        quantityField.set("v.errors", null);
    }

    var priceField = component.find("price");
    var price = priceField.get("v.value");
    if ($A.util.isEmpty(price) || isNaN(price) || (price <= 0.0)){
        validItem = false;
        priceField.set("v.errors", [{message:"Price can't be blank."}]);
    }
    else {
        quantityField.set("v.errors", null);
    }


    if(validItem){            
        var newItem = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(component.get("v.newItem")));

        console.log("Items before 'create': " + JSON.stringify(theItems));
        theExpenses.push(newItem);
        component.set("v.expenses", theItems);
        console.log("Items after 'create': " + JSON.stringify(theItems));
        theItems.push(newItem);
        component.set("v.items", theItems);

    }
}
})
```

and **campingListItemController.js** is as follows:

```
({packItem : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.item.Packed__c", "true");
    var btnClick = event.getSource();
    btnClick.set("v.disabled",true);
},
})
```

The Camping Item object is as follows:

[image: Camping Item Object]
In the above code though I am validating the inputs, getting no idea why still I am getting this error.

Comment: please confirm if you have put correct fields API names in `lightning:input` tag.

Comment: Hi @rahulgawale, yeah I have checked. They seem to be fine.

Comment: Check if the validations are working correctly.

Comment: BDW Quantity can be 1. but your logic is accepting only greater than 1, replace `(quantity <= 1)` with `(quantity < 1)`

Comment: Still facing the same issue after the change.

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check if the Quantity and Price are accepting only number and >0 , so update your error handling part with below.

```
if ($A.util.isEmpty(price) || isNaN(price) || (price <= 0.0))  {}
```

and  `if ($A.util.isEmpty(quantity) || isNaN(quantity) || (quantity <= 0)){
}`

Comment: Hi @ManishAnand, thanks for your response. Actually still I am getting the same issue even after modifying the code as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems here.

- Quantity can be 1. but your logic is accepting only greater than 1, replace `(quantity <= 1)` with `(quantity < 1)`
- `component.find` works on the basis of aura id, for Quantity aura id is `itemform` but you are checking it like `var quantityField = component.find("quantity");` which is wrong, change the `aura:id` to `quantity`.
- Same issue with price, `var priceField = component.find("price");`. change the `aura:id` to `price`.

Comment: Hi @rahulgawale, I have updated the code as per your suggestion. I have updated the original post as well. Still the same issue.

Comment: did you test your component manuallY?

Comment: Actually I am sorry. Being new to the salesforce framework, I don't have any idea how to do test it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your campingListController.js after changing the input field Id's in component.

```
// Simplistic error checking
//var validItem = true;

// Name must not be blank
var nameField = component.find("itemname").reduce(function (validSoFar, inputCmp){
    inputCmp.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
    return validSoFar && inputCmp.get('v.validity').valid;

        }, true);



// Quantity must not be blank
var quantityField = component.find("quantity").reduce(function (validSoFar, inputCmp){
    inputCmp.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
    return validSoFar && inputCmp.get('v.validity').valid;

        }, true);

//var quantity = nameField.get("v.value");


var priceField = component.find("price").reduce(function (validSoFar, inputCmp){
    inputCmp.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
    return validSoFar && inputCmp.get('v.validity').valid;

        }, true);




if(validItem){
    var newItem = component.get("v.newItem");
    console.log("Create item: " + JSON.stringify(newItem));
    //helper.createItem(component, newItem);
    //        var theItems = component.get("v.items");

// Copy the expense to a new object
// THIS IS A DISGUSTING, TEMPORARY HACK
var newItem = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item));

console.log("Items before 'create': " + JSON.stringify(theItems));
theExpenses.push(newItem);
component.set("v.expenses", theItems);
console.log("Items after 'create': " + JSON.stringify(theItems));
theItems.push(newItem);
component.set("v.items", theItems);

}
component.set("v.newItem",{'sobjectType':'Camping_Item__c',
            'Name': '',
            'Quantity__c': 0,
            'Price__c': 0,
            'Packed__c': false}); }
```